# Question about MySQL root user password strength - Do we want it here?

Tags: discussion

https://serverfault.com/questions/210034/why-is-it-bad-to-have-a-weak-mysql-user-password

Answer (score 3):

I think that would be on-topic here. "IT Security - Stack Exchange is [for IT security professionals to discuss vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq)"